# How can I flip the contents of a div? (Element at bottom becomes element at the top)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have this:

**TIMELINE** | *sort by **newest***

Event 4

Event 3

Event 2

Event 1

But I also want to display it as this:

**TIMELINE** | *sort by **oldest***

Event 1

Event 2

Event 3

Event 4

Each event is in a `<div>`. I do not want them to be in a `<li>` simply because it won't work with what I have already - a long story.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is each item present on a new line?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.